# Wordpress: Doctype tag getting wrapped in php tags

Tags: php, wordpress

At the top of my header.php file I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Options Framework Theme
 */

$post_type = get_post_type();
$is_single = is_single();
global $header_image_url;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

However, when I inspect the page in Chrome, I can see my doctype has managed to get wrapped in commented out php tags as show below, any idea how this has happened?

```
<!--?php<!DOCTYPE html-->
```

Comment: That most likely comes from a different file, which then in turn includes the header.php Probably easiest to find, if you do a search over all files in your IDE, and look for one that contains `<!--?php`

Comment: Yeah I've tried that, but can't find that in any file in my entire repo

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the problem. In my shortcodes.php file I had removed everything leaving `<?php` only, seemed that I needed a closing tag to make it `<?php ?>`